# Cleaning up conditional statements regarding new values

Tags: c#, .net

Please suggest ways of cleaning up this code.

```
Hashtable newValues = e.Values;

string NewPosition = null;
string NewFirst = null;
string NewLast = null;
string NewEmail = null;
int NewAppt = 0;

if (newValues["Position"] == null)
{
    NewPosition = "";
}
else
{
    NewPosition = newValues["Position"].ToString();
}

if (newValues["First Name"] == null)
{
    NewFirst = "";
}
else
{
    NewFirst = newValues["First Name"].ToString();
}

if (newValues["Last Name"] == null)
{
    NewLast = "";
}
else
{
    NewLast = newValues["Last Name"].ToString();
}

if (newValues["Email"] == null)
{
    NewEmail = "";
}
else
{
    NewEmail = newValues["Email"].ToString();
}

if (newValues["Appts"] == null)
{
    NewAppt = 0;
}
else
{
    NewAppt = 1;
}
```

Comment: I would suggest rewording the question to only have a representative snippet of that pattern, rather than repeating it 5 times

Comment: I didn't know that was an option.  Thanks @DaveZych.  I will keep that in mind for future postings like this one.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the *null-coalescing operator* [`??`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) like this:

```
NewPosition = (newValues["Position"] ?? "").ToString();
```

The core of this approach is this expression:

```
newValues["Position"] ?? ""
```

The `??` operator evaluates the left expression first (i.e. `newValues["Position"]`), and uses it as the result if it's not `null`. If the first expression is `null`, the second expression is evaluated, and its result is returned as the overall result of the expression.

For the last one, use `?`:

```
NewAppt = (newValues["Appts"] != null) ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: Does this also assign the value if it is not null?  Could you explain how this works just so I understand it?

Comment: And do I create the var first like string `NewPosition;` or Can I do a full assignment like string `NewPosition = (newValues["Position"] ?? "").ToString();`

Comment: @JamesWilson Since the expression fits on a single line, you can combine the declaration with initialization, like this: `var NewPosition = (newValues["Position"] ?? "").ToString();`

Comment: @JamesWilson Literally, ?? means "unless it is null, in which case use".

Comment: +1 Outstanding. Though I'd replace "" with `string.Empty` as a matter of habit.

Comment: -1, all this does is make it harder to maintain, reuse, and read the code.

Comment: @AMissico It does make things harder to developers unfamiliar with the `??` operator. Developers who are familiar with their basic technology, on the other hand, tend to appreciate the beauty and the brevity of this approach.

Comment: It makes it harder to change the code. If you use ?? you have have to change every statement. If you use a method that use ??, then you only have to change the method. Also, the method's implementation can change without affecting the statements. Our responsibility is to write code we can read, understand, and modify. Anyone can write crap.

Comment: @AMissico Note that `??` can be replaced with `+` without changing the validity of your statement. Yet very few people in their right mind write `AddOne(length)` instead of `length+1`, and it does not make anyone's code any harder to "maintain, reuse, and read".

Comment: Change the `??` statement to support `DBNull`. Tell me how long it takes you to change each statement. Then tell me how long it takes you if a method was used.

Comment: After you are done with that exercise. Change the `??` statements to support more than just a `string`. In the long run, using a method is the only logical choice.

Comment: @AMissico `??` operator does not support `DBNull`; minus operator `-` does not support strings. It would be very silly of me, however, to keep in mind an unlikely possibility of supporting `string`s some day while crafting my `int`-based solutions that needs a minus operator.

Answer (score 8):

While these are all good suggestions, I would wrap the code into a method.

```
NewPosition = GatherValue("Position");
NewFirst = GatherValue("First Name");

...
string GatherValue(string name) {
    return newValues[name] == null ? "" : newValues[name].ToString(); 
}
```

Comment: Does this offer any benefit over the other option, or is it just personal preference?

Comment: @James: Data container access method encapsulation/extraction.

Comment: I would need to make a seperate method for the int portion I am assuming?  Or modify the GatherValue to return a different value if the one passed in is Appts right?

Comment: @James Wilson; Yes, create another method for the int.

Comment: Personal preference based on a couple decades of experience. :O)

Comment: The immediate benefit is reuse and maintainence. Later, the code can be easily converted to an extension method for dictionaries (IDictionary) that can handle all data types.

Answer (score 3):

My preferred option is using the ternary operator when you are doing operations such as that.

Here is a brief example:

```
string NewPosition = newValues["Position"] != null ? newValues["Position"].ToString() : String.Empty;
```

The way it work is like this:

variable = boolean expression ? value that gets assigned when true : value that gets assigned when false.

You must be careful not to make your code difficult to read when using the ternary operator since it puts it in one line, however I find in most cases it makes it more readable.

Answer (score 3):

In case of `Hashtable`:

```
string value = ht["key"] as string ?? "";
```

But it's better to use generic thus type-safe `Dictionary<string, string>`:

```
string value = dic["key"] ?? "";
```

or `Dictionary<string, objects>`:

```
string value = ((string)dic["key"]) ?? "";
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a pattern that will reduce the lines, and IMO, make it easier to read.

Old:

```
if (newValues["Position"] == null)
{
    NewPosition = "";
}
else
{
    NewPosition = newValues["Position"].ToString();
}
```

New:

```
NewPosition = newValues["Position"] == null ? string.Empty : newValues["Position"].ToString();
```

As for the integer field:

`NewAppt = newValues["Appts"] == null ? 0 : 1;`

Documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Other than null coalescing operator, you could also simply add empty string

```
NewFirst = newValues["First Name"]+"";
```

For the following reason:

> 7.8.4 Addition operator
>
> String concatenation:
>
> string operator +(string x, string y); string operator +(string x,
>   object y); string operator +(object x, string y);
>
> These overloads of the binary + operator perform string concatenation.
>   If an operand of string concatenation is null, an empty string is
>   substituted. Otherwise, any non-string argument is converted to its
>   string representation by invoking the virtual ToString method
>   inherited from type object. If ToString returns null, an empty string
>   is substituted.

This will not work for integers/booleans/etc. Mostly just for strings or anything the .ToString() overload gives you that you actually want. For other cases i'd suggest null coalescing operator or some other approach like other answers provide here.

Comment: This is an old hack that relies on the storage variable to be a string. It is not an improvement. Over the years, this trick has caused by problems in two projects.

Comment: This makes is shorter at the expense of introducing a hack (relying on coincidence). Sometimes this is valid but in this case I would disagree. It is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

This code could be refactored like this:

```
HashTable newValues = e.Values;
string NewPosition = string.Empty;
string NewFirst = string.Empty; 
string NewLast = string.Empty;
string NewEmail = string.Empty;
int NewAppt;

NewPosition = (newValues["Position"] ?? string.Empty).ToString();
NewFirst = (newValues["First Name"] ?? string.Empty).ToString();
NewLast = (newValues["Last Name"] ?? string.Empty).ToString();
NewEmail = (newValues["Email"] ?? string.Empty).ToString();
NewAppt = newValues["Appts"] == null ? 0 : 1
```

Things to note:

- you don't need to declare the int as 0 - it defaults to 0, NB: C# structs (like int) are not nullable.
- If you are using a recent version of c#, use the var keyword to improve the readability of your variable declarations.

Comment: This will just result in null reference exceptions when the values are null

Comment: Now it's just like several other existing answers...

Comment: @Servy: Doesn't deserve downvote though imo.

Comment: Why initialize the local string variables when they are instantly replaced? Extra coding and loss of performance.

Comment: Valid question. The only reason is because I hate initializing variables as null as the OP did. I know you can use string.IsNullOrEmpty() but a lazy programmer might not bother in the future when changing the code - leading to trouble. Eg: imagine if someone removed one of the lines that assign values to the strings, or changed it. Accessing the variable later on would cause an exception. So I guess I'm trying to make it foolproof.

Comment: @Kryptonite Actually, as it seems these are all done as local variables in a method, they won't be `null` if you remove the initialization altogether. They'll be *undefined* until assigned, which the assignments immediately do.

Answer (score 0):

Given you're using c# 4 I'd suggest to create a static extension method for your values.

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static string ToValueOrStringEmpty(this object myString)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)myString) 
               ? string.Empty 
               : (string)myString;
    }
}
```

Your code now is:

```
NewPosition = newValues["Position"].ToValueOrStringEmpty();
NewFirst = newValues["First Name"].ToValueOrStringEmpty();
NewLast = newValues["Last Name"].ToValueOrStringEmpty();
NewEmail = newValues["Email"].ToValueOrStringEmpty();
```